# Is there a way to hide current GUI elements on netBeans GUI builder to build over them for another button click?

Tags: java, netbeans, gui-builder

I am trying to develop a simple GUI application using Apache NetBeans.
I have built all elements for the button Enter new data as the picture shows:
[image]

Dragging and dropping elements over it is not feasible. I am looking to build this layout for search button over the previous elements. I know how to hide previous elements and display search GUI elements but designing it through drag and drop is not possible.
[image]

All I've done for Enter new Data button is setVisible(true) for all elements in the enterNewDataButton actionPerformed method.

Comment: A `CardLayout` may be what you need. Read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: thanks man I got your pointer, there was an option to enclose all components in a tab. Thanks for the reply